# how to change Labels in primeng toggle button Angular?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have info button as component. And I want to use it more than one time with different Labels. Primeng has onLabel attribute, but it doesnt work in parent component. May be somebody know how to do that?

**info-button.component**
html:

```
<p-toggleButton
    onIcon="pi pi-info"
    offIcon="pi pi-times">i</p-toggleButton>
```

ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-infobutton',
  templateUrl: './info-icon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./info-icon.component.css']
})
export class IconComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  onLabel: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I call info button in some component, more than ones
**some.component**
html:

```
<app-infobutton class="col-1" [onLabel]="'text'" ></app-infobutton>
<app-infobutton class="col-1" [onLabel]="'text2'" ></app-infobutton>
```

ts:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit{
  text: string = "some text";
  text2: string = "another text";
}
```

this 'some Text' I get as attribute. not like label.

Output

```
<app-infoicon _ngcontent-cee-c3="" class="col-1" _nghost-cee-c5="" ng-reflect-on-label="some Text" <!--this is my output-->>
   <div _ngcontent-cee-c5="" class="info-icon icon-default">
      <p-togglebutton _ngcontent-cee-c5="" officon="pi pi-times" onicon="pi pi-info" ng-reflect-on-icon="pi pi-info" ng-reflect-off-icon="pi pi-times">
           <div class="ui-button ui-togglebutton ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-state-active" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
               <span class="ui-button-text ui-unselectable-text">Yes <!--this is Label--></span></div>
       </p-togglebutton>
    </div>
 </app-infoicon>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend your template like this

```
<p-toggleButton
    [onLabel]="onLabel"
    onIcon="pi pi-info"
    offIcon="pi pi-times">i</p-toggleButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the `PrimeNg` component library as that was the first library i found using the selctor `<p-togglebutton>`

Based on the documentation, to be able to show a label, you have to pass the label attribute to the component like this:

```
<p-toggleButton onLabel="I confirm"></p-toggleButton>
```

So based on your example I assume you have to pass you're label attribute to the component like this:

```
<p-toggleButton
  [onLabel]="onLabel"
  onIcon="pi pi-info"
  offIcon="pi pi-times">i</p-toggleButton>
```