# How to add the text “ON” and “OFF” to toggle button in angular using prime ng

Tags: angular, primeng

On my project I wanted to add a text on my existing toggle code.So I wanted like this, When toggles ON it should display the text "ON" and display the "OFF" text if toggles off.I just wanted only to input "ON" and "OFF" text.

Comment: Did you read their documentation here? https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v10-lts/#/togglebutton

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change Labels in primeng toggle button Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887379/how-to-change-labels-in-primeng-toggle-button-angular)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
<label>off</label>
<mat-slide-toggle></mat-slide-toggle>
<label>on</label>
```

Add some if conditions if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the `onLabel` and `offLable` properties.

```
<p-toggleButton onLabel="ON" offLabel="OFF"></p-toggleButton>
```

If you need to still call your toggle code, you can add `(onChange)="handleToggle($event)"` as well